# Check if a number is between 2 values

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am new to prolog and have am trying to write a program that will do the following tell me if a number is between 2 values I can do the following:

```
between(L, X, R) :- 
    X > L, X < R.
```

and doing between(1, 3, 5) works, but I would like it to be able to do between(1, X, 5) and have prolog return all the values in between so in this case X = 2, X = 3, X = 4, I get why my solution doesn't because it needs to be have been initialised, but I cannot think of a solution to this problem, can this type of thing just not be done in prolog?, and help would be great thanks

Comment: Well I am not much of a prolog person, but to me, what you want can not be achieved without adding some extra definitions. You want prolog to return all X that satisfy between(1, X, 5) but prolog does not know what should it try to substitute for X. It will only try substitutions with currently defined objects. Only way to achieve what you want is create a recursive function yourself that would try numbers from start to end, but I guess you already know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want to predefine all numbers: let prolog create a list with possible entries and state your `X` has to be one of them. To understand the code you have to have knowledge about lists in prolog, especially Head and Tail notation of lists.

```
betweenList(L,R,[]):- 
    L>=R.
betweenList(L,R,[L|Rest]):- 
    L<R,
    LL is L+1,
    betweenList(LL,R,Rest).

between(L, X, R) :- 
    betweenList(L, R, [L| List]),
    member(X, List).

?- between(1,X,5).
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
false.
```

`betweenList(L,R,List)` creates a List of all numbers between `L` and `R`, including `L` (as head element), excluding `R`. So if you want to generate a List without `L`, it is the easiest to just call `betweenList(L, R, [L| List])` so `List` will not include `L`. Now `X` just has to be a member of `List`. The `member/2` predicate can be easily written as well if you don't want to use the inbuild predicate.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this:

```
digit(0).
digit(1).
digit(2).
digit(3).
digit(4).
digit(5).
digit(6).
digit(7).
digit(8).
digit(9).

between(L, X, U) :- digit(L), digit(X), digit(U), L < X, X < U.
```

Tests:

```
?- between(2, X, 5).
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
false.

?- between(2, 7, U).
U = 8 ;
U = 9.
```

Alternatively, you may want to look into [Constraint logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_logic_programming).

Incidentally, Prolog already has a `between/3`:

```
?- between(1, 5, X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5.
```

although it's "illogical": you can't run it backwards, as the above definition.